# Errores en XAMPP al enviar formulario PHP a Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una bdd llamada 'hospital', con una tabla llamada 'sala_habitación',que a su vez tiene los campos ID_habitación, Número, Planta y Disponibilidad. La idea en el aplicativo es mostrar un formulario que envíe datos a mysql y que a la vez muestre en tiempo real los datos que tiene la tabla, esta segunda parte me funciona ,el archivo log de error me muestra lo siguiente pero creo que mi sintaxis del código está bien formulada:

> [15-Dec-2022 13:03:45 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was
> not defined in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hospitalweb/secciones/sala_habitacion.php:24
> Stack trace:
> #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hospitalweb/secciones/sala_habitacion.php(24):
> PDOStatement->execute()
> #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hospitalweb/secciones/vista_salahabitacion.php(2):
> include('/Applications/X...')
> #2 {main}   thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hospitalweb/secciones/sala_habitacion.php
> on line 24

archivo de conexión con la bdd:

```
 <?php
class BD{
public static $instancia=null;
public static function crearInstancia(){
    
    if(  !isset(self::$instancia) ){
     $opciones[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
     self::$instancia = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hospital', 'root', '', $opciones);
     echo "conectado...";

    }

    return self::$instancia;
}
}

?>
```

a continuación el archivo vista_salahabitacion

```
>  <?php include('../templates/cabecera.php'); ?> <?php
> include('../secciones/sala_habitacion.php'); ?>
> 
> <h1 class="display-3"> Habitaciones y Salas</h1> <br/>
> 
> <div class="row"> <div class="col-12">
>     <br>
>      <div class="row"> <div class="col-5"> <div class="mb-3">
> 
> <form action="" method="POST"> <div class="card">    <div
> class="card-header">HABITACIÓN</div>    <div class="card-body">   
> <div class="mb-3">  <label for=""
> class="form-label">ID_habitación</label>  <input type="text"   
> class="form-control"    name="ID_habitación"    id="ID_habitación"   
> aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="ID_habitación"> </div>   <div
> class="mb-3"> <label for="" class="form-label">Número</label>  <input
> type="text"    class="form-control"    name="Número"    id="Número"   
> aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Número"> </div>   <div
> class="mb-3"> <label for="" class="form-label">Planta</label>  <input
> type="text"    class="form-control"    name="Planta"    id="Planta"   
> aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Planta"> </div>   <div
> class="mb-3"> <label for="" class="form-label">Disponibilidad</label> 
> <input type="text"    class="form-control"    name="Disponibilidad"   
> id="Disponibilidad"    aria-describedby="helpId"
> placeholder="Disponibilidad"> </div> <br>
> 
> <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">    <button
> type="submit" name="accion" value="agregar" class="btn
> btn-success">Agregar</button>    <button type="submit" name="accion"
> value="editar" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>    <button
> type="submit" name="accion" value="borrar" class="btn
> btn-danger">Borrar</button> </div> </div> </div>
> 
> 
> 
> </div>  </div>
> 
>  </form>
> 
> 
> <div class="col-7"> <table class="table">    <thead>
>        <tr>
>            <th>ID</th>
>            <th>NÚMERO</th>
>            <th>PLANTA</th>
>            <th>DISPONIBILIDAD</th>
>              </tr> </thead> <tbody>   <?php foreach($lista_salahabitacion as $sala){ ?>    <tr>
>            <td> <?php echo $sala['ID_habitación']; ?> </td>
>            <td> <?php echo $sala['Número']; ?> </td>
>            <td> <?php echo $sala['Planta']; ?> </td>
>            <td> <?php echo $sala['Disponibilidad']; ?> </td>
>            </tr> <?php } ?> </tbody> </table> <?php include('../templates/piepagina.php'); ?>
```

y por último el sala_habitacion.php

```
`<?php
include_once '../configuracion/bd.php';


$conexionBD=BD::crearInstancia();

$ID_habitación=isset($_POST['ID_habitación'])?$_POST['ID_habitación']:'';
$Número=isset($_POST['Número'])?$_POST['Número']:'';
$Planta=isset($_POST['Planta'])?$_POST['Planta']:'';
$Disponibilidad=isset($_POST['Disponibilidad'])?$_POST['Disponibilidad']:'';
$accion=isset($_POST['accion'])?$_POST['accion']:'';


if($accion!=''){
switch($accion){

   case 'agregar':
     $sql="INSERT INTO sala_habitación (ID_habitación, Número, Planta, Disponibilidad) VALUES (:ID_habitación,:Número,:Planta,:Disponibilidad)";
     $consulta=$conexionBD->prepare($sql);
     $consulta->bindParam(':ID_habitación',$ID_habitación);
    $consulta->bindParam(':Número',$Número);
    $consulta->bindParam(':Planta',$Planta);
    $consulta->bindParam(':Disponibilidad',$Disponibilidad);
    $consulta->execute();
   break;

   case 'editar':
   $sql="UPDATE sala_habitación SET ID_habitación=:ID_habitación, Número=:Número, Planta=:Planta, Disponibilidad=:Disponibilidad WHERE ID_habitación=:ID_habitación";
   $consulta=$conexionBD->prepare($sql);
   $consulta->bindParam(':ID_habitación,$ID_habitación');
   $consulta->execute();
break;

   case 'borrar':
   $sql="DELETE FROM sala_habitación WHERE ID_habitación=$ID_habitación";
   $consulta=$conexionBD->prepare($sql);
   $consulta->bindParam(':ID_habitación,$ID_habitación');
   $consulta->execute();
break;
}


}


$consulta=$conexionBD->prepare("SELECT * FROM sala_habitación");
$consulta->execute();
$lista_salahabitacion=$consulta->fetchAll(); 
?>
```

`

Comment: El error que estás recibiendo es de SQL no de php, al parecer el campo que deseas guardar no lo has creado.

Answer (score 0):

El error que se está presentando en tu código es que estás intentando ejecutar una consulta a la base de datos utilizando parámetros que no han sido definidos. En concreto, en la línea 24 del archivo **`sala_habitacion.php`** se puede ver que se está intentando ejecutar una consulta preparada utilizando PDO y se están pasando cuatro parámetros a la función `execute()` pero en la consulta sólo se están esperando dos.

Una posible solución a este problema sería modificar la consulta preparada para que espere cuatro parámetros en lugar de dos. Por ejemplo, cambiando la línea 23 del archivo **`sala_habitacion.php`** de esta forma:

```
$sentencia = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO sala_habitacion (ID_habitación, Número, Planta, Disponibilidad) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

De esta forma, la consulta estaría esperando cuatro parámetros y se podría ejecutar sin problemas utilizando la siguiente línea de código:

```
$sentencia->execute([$_POST['ID_habitación'], $_POST['Número'], $_POST['Planta'], $_POST['Disponibilidad']]);
```

También es importante asegurarse de que los nombres de los campos en la base de datos coinciden exactamente con los nombres de las variables que se están utilizando en el formulario. Si hay algún error en los nombres, es posible que la consulta no se ejecute correctamente y se produzca un error.